# How do I get the contents of a web page that is behind a log-in page?

Tags: c#, https

This works, expect, I'm downloading the string of the log-in page and not the actual page (url variable).

How do I get the contents of a page that is behind a log-in?

```
var credentials = new NetworkCredential { UserName = "xxxxxx", Password = "yyyyyy" };
using (var client = new WebClient())
{
    client.Credentials = credentials;

    string page = client.DownloadString(url);

    if (page.Contains("cheetah"))
    {
         MessageBox.Show("cheetah exists");
    }
    else
    {
         MessageBox.Show("NOPE");
    }
 }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
string page = client.DownloadData(url);
```